# Restore data from Pixel 3a to Galaxy S22

Tags: google-backup

I am trying to restore data from a Pixel 3a cloud backup to a Galaxy S22. Both are running Android 12 with the May security update. When I go to restore, it says, "This backup is from a device with a newer version of Android. Some data may not restore to your new device." Is there any way around this?

Comment: Google not only provides security updates but als feature updates every few months may be that is the cause of this warning. On the other hand Samsung makes a lot of modifications to Android so no matter what you try both phones even on the same major version and patch level will always be different to a certain degree. But the differences should be marginally only affecting a few features. So the only way I see is to accept it and after migration check all (for you important) settings.

Comment: D2D transfer apps should have full access [1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pixelmigrate), [2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.easyMover) (never used)